# Git Extensions fails to push

Tags: git

I have a local git repo (on Windows machine) with a remote on gitlab.
When I try to push from the Git Extensions GUI, I get this error:

```
git: 'git@gitlab.com' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

When I view the command that failed (in the Git Extensions command log) it's:

```
git push -v --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

But if I run this command from the command line (git bash), it succeeds.

I assume it's a setting/config problem in Git Extensions, but I am unable to fix it.

Two data points:

1. This used to work until I updated Git Extensions a few weeks back. The current version is 3.5.3.12551, git is 2.32.0.windows.
2. The URL in the .git/config is

   url = git@gitlab.com:the-path-to-my-repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only recent change regarding SSH went into [Git Extension 3.5.1](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/blob/release/3.5/GitUI/Resources/ChangeLog.md#version-351-04-jul-2021) (Jul. 2021)

> [9112](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/9112) SSH broken after upgrade to 3.5.0 (due to breaking setting change)

So:

- check if 3.5.0 works
- check if GIT_SSH was set ([PR 9182](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/9182))

> In 3.4 or earlier, the OpenSSH path was set in the registry, even if it was supposed to be empty (handled in [#9149](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/9149)).
> If the OpenSSH path is corrupted (as reported and discussed in [#9112](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/9112) when upgrading GE) it will just be ignored.
> This will also recover from issues if the Git installation is changed.

Comment: Uninstalled 3.5.3, installed 3.5.0, push works now.

Comment: So should I file a bug on 3.5.3?

Comment: @AmirKatz It sure looks like it: you can report it on https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues